# determine effective permission source In Active directory

Tags: powershell, security, directory

How can I determine the source of a permission?

A user, from the root of the domain has write permission to all group objects and their properties. I can see this access in the effective permissions but I can't tell where it comes from.

Access in the ACLS shows accounts and groups with access but I can't figure out where this access is coming from.

Here's what I've tried

```
dsacls dc=contoso,dc=org|findstr "username"
```

but it doesn't do anything.

```
get-acl AD:dc=contoso,dc=org
```

1. How do you find the source of a user's privileges in Active Directory?
2. How do you find what the "effective permissions tab used to calculate the access"?

[A screenshot of the Advanced Security Settings dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUdd7.png)

Comment: Have a look at the NTFS Security module for PowerShell, it looks like it might have a few cmdlets that could get you want you need: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069043/how-to-get-effective-permissions-with-powershell-for-an-attribute-on-the-ad-user

Comment: I imported that module. The ACEs that I see don't point me to the permission. I can see WHAT the permissions are but I can't see HOW they were determined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
get-acl AD:dc=contoso,dc=org
```

Could you please try this:

```
get-acl "AD:\dc=contoso,dc=org"
```

If you pipe it to *Get-Member*, you would be able to see all the useful methods for the same. You can directly access them using Dot. That should fulfill your requirement I believe.

```
  (Get-Acl (Get-ADUser User).distinguishedname).access | select identityreference, accesscontroltype
```

For Non-inherited users, try the below ; else remove the where condition:

```
(Get-ACL "AD:CN=User,OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com").Access | Where {$_.IsInherited -eq $FALSE}| Select IdentityReference,AccessControlType, IsInherited
```

Comment: Most of the options here I can do in the GUI but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I have nodified the ans.. Check it please