# How to get a list of groups a user can administer (add/remove users to) in active directory

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

Is it possible using powershell or C#, to get a list of groups a person has access to modify (i.e, write, read+write, full control, etc.)?

---

We've tried using the common powershell commands (`Get-ADGroup`, `Get-ADGroupMember`, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, etc.) but they are geared towards what group you have a membership to, rather than what groups you have access to modify.

There is also a `managedBy` property in AD but that is optional and doesn't seem to actually control permissions.

Part of the issue that makes this complex is that being able to modify a group isn't just as simple as the user having permissions to modify the group - sometimes you can modify a group because you are a member of another group that has that permission.

I was hoping someone could chime in on whether there was a "correct" way to go about this problem (ideally without having to traverse the entire AD and look at every single group and permission).

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin - added more details!

Comment: Are you under restrictions with regard to installing new modules? If not, you might want to take a look at [How to Get Effective Permissions With PowerShell for an Attribute on the AD User Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069043/how-to-get-effective-permissions-with-powershell-for-an-attribute-on-the-ad-user)

Comment: Awesome - giving it a try, definitely seeing some permissions errors but this looks promising!